# Filter/Sort Listbox Items

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a listbox with items filled with stackpanels such as:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock x:Name="accessionNumber" Text="{Binding Path=accessionNumber}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=orderRadDept}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

There are multiple stackpanels in each item and each stackpanel is bound to a different value in a sql database.

I'm trying to filter/sort the listbox items without having to requery the database each time.

For instance,

```
IEnumerable<radOrder> filteredOrders2 =
                dc.radOrders.Where(o => o.orderRadDept == "CT")
                    .OrderBy(o => o.orderDateTime);
            OnScreenList.ItemsSource = filteredOrders2;
```

...will do exactly what I need to do by querying the database and returning the items I want.  However, we're going to get a loss in performance if we do it this way.

What I'd like to do is take the `OnScreenList` and just sort/filter it, and this is were I'm running into problems.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
             List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>(OnScreenList.Items.Cast<ListItem>());
             list.Sort();
```

...and I'm stuck trying to refer to the datamembers of the list items.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

(Sorry if this is a dumb question.  I'm trying to teach myself C#, SQL, and wpf/xaml all at the same time.)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it would be good idea to filter on the `ListBox` items directly. I would suggest a different approach.

Create a List `AllItems` that will be filled once from SQL database. This list would have all the records which have to be displayed in list box in other words it would be super set of records that can be displayed.

Create another List `DisplayList` which will be used as `ItemsSource` of your `ListBox`.

Now whenever you want to filer the items, apply the filter on `AllItems` list and store results in `DisplayList`.

In this way you won't need to query database very time plus you can easily filter and sort the `DisplayList` list

Comment: I would like to know why -1? What is wrong with this approach? Kindly explain so that I don't make this mistake again